# Proper unicode support

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Right now I have a first gen windows phone, with 7.8 installed [Omnia 7]. It does not have proper unicode support [I'll be precise, it does not show malayalam characters, on facebook for instance]. I looked around if WP8 supports this and it seems like it doesn't.

My question is, does WP8 have proper unicode rendering? If not throughout the OS, AT THE LEAST on the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpfeatures/malayalam-unicode-support-in-windows-phone-8/4d144e4f-eea4-430b-b26d-945e2d98df00

Sorry, Malayalam is not presently supported.

I did find this, though: http://malayalam4mobile.hafees.com/