# C# Sending Hex string to tcp socket

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, request

I'm trying to send a hex string to a tcp socket. I have some problems with the format or conversion of this string, cause I'm not very sure what the format its using.

I've written a WindowsPhone app which is working fine based on Socket Class.
This app emulates request, that are normaly send from a desktop program to a device which hosts a webservice.

Via wireshark, I found out, that the webservice will accept an input stream (think its in hex) and returns a 2nd. hex stream which contains the data I need.

So the desktop app is sending a stream
and Wireshark shows when  :

Data (8 bytes) 
Data: 62ff03fff00574600
Length: 8

Now I've tried a lot to reproduce this stream. I thougt, it used to be a UTF8 string and converted this stream to this format. But every time I send it, is see in Wireshark the following output: 62c3bf03c3bf00574600

As far as i've investigated 62 = b but ff send always c3bf.

Does somebody know how to send this stream in the right format?

Cheers,
Jo

Comment: Could you show some code representation that what and how you are sending data and what you are getting as response and what should be the output?

Comment: The code is almost exactly the same as the M$ sample here. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: the data send after conversion from hex to string used to be something like the string : bÿÿ So, the formating seemes to work. Then I do ... result = client.Send(sendString); where sendString is bÿÿ. The send method in the example does then a copnversion from string to payload where payload is a byte array (byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)). And this will send to the device via socket connection. But, the problem is, that these 0x00ff arent converted to ÿ but to c3bf when I resolve the data in wireshark. Any idea?

Comment: PS: because the server device doesnt recognize the data send, its returning me ERR1 which shows me, that its working fine but the data send dont trigger the right output.

Comment: this is the communication in Wireshark: `00000020  62 ff 03 ff 00 57 46 00 0000006E  e2 ff 03 ff 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 1d 00
00000028  62 ff 03 ff 00 45 58 00 0000007D  e2 ff 03 ff 00 a0 ee d3  00 bc 00 00000030  62 ff 03 ff 00 9d 00 00 00000088  e2 ff 03 ff 00 a5 b4 00  00 c4 00
00000038  62 ff 03 ff 00 43 5a 00 00000093  e2 ff 03 ff 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 000000A3  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000B3  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
000000C3  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000D3  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1d  00

Comment: You are sending payload to the TCP server "payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))."

Could you please show me the TCp server side code that receive this message?

Comment: No, sorry. This is a device with included web- or socket service. I dont know what its doing internaly. Meanwhile I found out, that I used to convert to unicode. (byte[] payload = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);) is captured in Wireshark as 6200ff000300ff000000570046000000. You can see, that every hex byte is now composed in two byte form. Can you tell me how to get rid of these leading 00. I think the form is now 0x0062 0x00ff,.... when I could get rid of 00 its OK I think. Maybe I can remove every odd byte in the byte[] and it'll be OK...

Comment: you just need to remember the way TCP server decode the received bytes from TCP client. in client side you need to follow the same mechanism to encode so that TCP server can decode it correctly. nothing else i can hep you in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The socket transport shouldn't care, the content of a TCP packet is binary representing "whatever".
From the code you pointed to in the comments:

```
byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
socketEventArg.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);
...
response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
response = response.Trim('\0');
```

At the end of the socket send/receive (data == response).  If that isn't occurring you need to figure how where the problem is.  The first step is to write some very simple code like so:

```
string source = "your problem text string";
byte[] encode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
target = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encode, 0, encode.Length);
Debug.Assert(source == target);
```

If that works, then output the 'encode' array can check to make sure that is contained in the packet data where it is being send, then verify that that is what is being received.  If you are sending the right data but receiving it corrupted you have serious problems ... I doubt you find that but if so write a very simple test program that sends and receives on the same machine (localhost) to see if it is repeatable.

If I had to guess I would say that the characters being encoded are not Unicode or that Win phone doesn't properly support it ([Proper unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700827/proper-unicode-support)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The server isnt the problem. Its well treathing the request but the data send is incorrect. When I debug the app, I can see, that payload gets its data array holding the data I await but the prob is still, that I used to send 62 ff 03 ff but its doing 0062 00ff 0003 00ff with `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data)`. So in the end, the server does not understand the request and its response ERR1 is absolutely OK. My app gets this response and shows it. So OK too.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't know the protocol / the encoding the server expects you can only replay the known messages, like the bytes you provided in your question.

Therefore you just define directly the byte array like this:

```
byte[] payload = new byte[] {0x62, 0xff, 0x03, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x05, 0x74, 0x60};
```

and send it over the socket like you did with the encoded string before. The server should now accept the message like it was sent by the client you sniffed.